# Scheduling a Task for every minute in Windows 2012

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

I need to schedule a `Task` inside of my Windows 2012 to run *every* minute, how would one accomplish that? This is my `Task`:

```
C:\>C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\wget\bin\wget.exe --spider --quiet http://XXX/XXX.aspx
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\wget/etc/wgetrc

C:\>
```

I've tried `Task Scheduler`->`Create Task`, but I can't figure out how to schedule to run it every minute.

this is equivalent in *NIX world:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * *   wget --spider --quiet http://XXX/XXX.aspx
$
```

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though the GUI drop down menu only goes down to 5 minutes... just try manually typing in 1 minute.

[image]

Comment: thanks, you forgot "for a duration of" `Indefinitely`, but I got the idea) thanks!

Comment: where can I see logs about this task? it shows me that it ran successfully yet in IIS logs I'm not seeing a hit.

Comment: Well that's complicated. As long as *something* was excecuted and returned, the Task Scheduler thinks everything's cool. But in reality what was executed might not have been what you intended. If wget has any logging parameters, now would be a good time to use them. As well as adding 2>&1>out.log to the end of your command for debugging purposes to capture all stdout and stderr output from the command that was executed.

Comment: If that doesn't do it for you, I humbly suggest submitting that problem as a new question, as in my opinion that's a whole different issue than what was asked in this question.